# How to resolve "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" issue?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have two different modules. one module run on local network and other on web. The local module accepts different parameters. According to passed parameters it executes specific code snippet.

I want to send input from web to module that runs locally so that it can run with given paramenter. but I am getting error :

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.xx.xx:8080/myurl. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."
```

In my case I have to send request to specific IP address (where servelet processes a input) from mydomain.
How do I set cross domain request using jsp to resolve above given error?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use below code for the same:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```